# How do I update a local file's timestamp to match the one on the server?

Tags: timestamp, touch, wget

For historical reasons I like keeping the original timestamps when it matters, and I downloaded a large file with the browser instead of using wget (which preserves timestamps by default). Now I have that large file and instead of downloading it again, I'd rather update its timestamp if possible.

An idea would be to generate the unix timestamp from the original, and apply it with touch. But can wget do this?

I looked at [wget's help](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping.html), but it doesn't look like it can address my use case.